# Explaining pharse 「今日のイチオシ」 - part ~オシ

Tags: words, meaning

Recently I have received the e-mail from レコチョク online music store - and the is the title 今日のイチオシ. It translates as "Today's choices". But abbreviation (?) at the end ~オシ I can't understand/translate.. And also the name itself of the shop レコチョク is not very clear to me - the part ~チョク. Maybe it is also some abbreviation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「オシ」 comes from the verb 「[推]{お}す」, which means "to recommend".  You may already know the word 「[推薦]{すいせん}する」, which means the same.  Notice the same kanji is used in both.

「イチ」, of course, means 「[一番]{いちばん}」.  Thus, 「イチオシ」 is a colloquial (kind of slangy but not too much) word meaning "***one's best recommendation***".

Finally, 「チョク」 in 「レコチョク」 is 「[直]{ちょく}」 in kanji.  It means "direct".

According to Wikipedia, the company was named レコチョク because it is directly funded by the record companies -- 「レコード[会社直営]{がいしゃちょくえい}」.  It took the 「レコ」 and「直」 parts and put them together.

http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B3%E3%83%81%E3%83%A7%E3%82%AF